# Wlan usb adapter not working with Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, ubuntu-gnome

I am having problems with a Sitecom (Model: WL-168 v1 004v [Link to website](http://www.sitecomlearningcentre.com/products/wl-168v1004/wlan-usb-adapter-54g)) USB wireless adapter: after selecting the network I want to connect to, the "connecting" status ends and nothing happens.

I start by reporting two important things:

1. The same adapter works perfectly on Debian jessie (lastest version), without any problem.
2. I have already looked up on the Internet (I read 4-5 topics on this website too) and tried the suggested solutions, none of them worked for me.

Here is the message related to my problem:

**"dmesg | grep wlx000cf63c72822" output, soon after I select the network I want to connect to:**

```
[ 2659.147924] wlx000cf63c7282: authenticate with 30:91:8f:e5:17:db
[ 2659.323064] wlx000cf63c7282: send auth to 30:91:8f:e5:17:db (try 1/3)
[ 2659.326558] wlx000cf63c7282: authenticated
[ 2664.328171] wlx000cf63c7282: aborting authentication with 30:91:8f:e5:17:db by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Some details about my machine (a Fujitsu desktop computer):

**OS and Kernel Version:**

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.04 
DISTRIB_CODENAME=zesty 
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.04"
4.10.0-21-generic
```

One further detail: I am using *UbuntuGNOME*.

**ifconfig output:**

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::90b3:ebde:b2fe:9935  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:19:99:a2:d5:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13457  bytes 14627941 (14.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8924  bytes 1258011 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1193  bytes 89838 (89.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1193  bytes 89838 (89.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx000cf63c7282: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether fa:f3:82:0a:cc:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**lshw -class network output:**

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:19:99:a2:d5:c2
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw ip=192.168.1.200 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:fc304000-fc304fff memory:fc300000-fc303fff memory:c0400000-c040ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:6
       logical name: wlx000cf63c7282
       serial: 5a:72:af:02:24:2b
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8187 driverversion=4.10.0-21-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

**rfkill list all output:**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

As I said, I tried many solutions, but they could not fix my problem.
I read about *linux-backports-modules-wireless* packages, which I thought might be helpful, but I could not find any way to download/install them.

Do not hesitate to ask me for more details, I will help you as much as I can.

Comment: Did you disable MAC randomization?

Comment: You were right, this solved my problem. Thanks!